# jQuery AJAX call specified as POST is recognized as GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have an jQuery AJAX call like so:

```
var ajaxStuff = $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : customURL,
    data : {
        myData : 'myData'
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false
}).responseText;
console.log(ajaxStuff);
```

However, in the PHP when I ask what request method I'm using:

```
echo ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
```

It returns:

```
GET
```

Why can't my AJAX call be recognized as a POST?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the URL at `customURL` do any redirects?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it is highly advised that you do not do `async : false`

Comment: `async:false` is almost never the solution -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name of the method is `method`, not `type`:

```
var ajaxStuff = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',  ////// not "type"
    url : customURL,
    data : {
        myData : 'myData'
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false
}).responseText;
console.log(ajaxStuff);
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

`$.ajax()` defaults to GET when no method is specified, or when the parameter is named incorrectly.

Comment: This depends entirely on the version of jquery being used

Comment: `method`: v1.9+, `type`: any version and an alias for `method`

Comment: I changed the parameter name to method. Still same result but thanks for clarifying this.